# Blazor how to await properly for data to be loaded before printing?

Tags: async-await, blazor

I want to print some data on a'blank-page' the data gets loaded async from mongodb in a List (print is done by JS via JSRuntime).
I call a razor page with a blank layout and do a foreeach loop from the List to create a table. The problem that I have is, that the pages gets rendered before the list of the foreeachloop is loaded.
How do I wait properly till list is loaded 100% and then show/ print the page?

Right now I use a work around; look at the 'OnInitialized()' while loop. Pretty ugly.

```cs
@page "/PrintPages/Praxen"

@inject PraxisKontaktePrintVM ViewModel
@inject IJSRuntime IJS
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManger

       <table class="table">
           <tbody>
               @foreach (var praxis in ViewModel.AerzteLst)
               {
                   <tr>
                       <td>
                           @foreach (var dr in praxis.PraxisDresNamensLst)
                           {
                               <p>@dr</p>
                           }
                       </td>
           </tr>
               }
           </tbody>
       </table>

@code {
   protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
       //If I dont wait till Lists are loaded a empty list is show on the print because of async load DB
       //TODO get rid of this work around
       var TODO3 = 0;

       bool myWait = true;
       var counter = 0;

       while (ViewModel.AerzteLst.Count <= 0 && myWait)
       {
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
           counter += 1;
           if (counter >= 50)
           {
               myWait = false;
           }
       }
   }

   protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
   {
       // execute conditionally for loading data, otherwise this will load
       // every time the page refreshes; on the second button press data is there
       if (firstRender)
       {
           StateHasChanged();

           IJS.InvokeVoidAsync("Print");
       }
       NavigationManger.NavigateTo("/praxen");
   }
}
```

The ViewModel is an injected Class via Startup.cs. And looks like this:

```
    public class PraxisKontaktePrintVM : BaseViewModel
    {
        readonly MongoAux _mongoAux;

        public PraxisKontaktePrintVM(MongoAux mongoAux)
        {
            _mongoAux = mongoAux;
            IniStartup();
        }

        public List<ArztPraxis> HeadLst = new();
        public List<ArztPraxis> BodyLst = new();

        public async void IniStartup()
        {
            var res = await _mongoAux.ReadAllAsync<ArztPraxis>(MySecret.MyArztPraxisColletionName);
            HeadsLst =  res.Where(x => x.IsActiv == true && x.PraxisFachrichtung == MySecret.FachrichtungEnum.HeadArzt).ToList();
            BodyLst = res.Where(x => x.IsActiv == true && x.PraxisFachrichtung == MySecret.FachrichtungEnum.BodyArzt).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct problem is `async void IniStartup()`. An async void method runs unobserved, the root cause of your problems. Almost always avoid `async void`.
And never use `Thread.Sleep()` in real code.

Step 1: make it an `async Task` and don't call it from the constructor:

```cs
    public PraxisKontaktePrintVM(MongoAux mongoAux)
    {
        _mongoAux = mongoAux;
        //IniStartup();        // remove
    }
        
    public async Task IniStartup()
    {
        ... // as before
    }
```

Note that this is also in line with best practices for DI, don't put (heavy) logic in a constructor. And constructors are not async.

Step 2: call it from your page in the correct order:

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await ViewModel.IniStartup();
    StateHasChanged();      // in case IniStartup has multiple async steps
    await Task.Delay(1);    // make sure the last state is rendered
    await IJS.InvokeVoidAsync("Print");     // await it        
    NavigationManger.NavigateTo("/praxen"); // and off again 
}
```

Remove the OnAfterRender, you don't seem to need it.