# How can I turn on/off a Loading… while a page initializes in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, bunit

I want to put up a Loading… overlay while a page is loading. If everything was in my razor page then I could make it visible as the first line in `OnInitializedAsync()` and hide it as the last line.

But I have children components in the page. And as they all also have their own `OnInitializedAsync()`, and that is async for all of them, they complete in a random order.

So, for making the overlay visible, is the containing page’s `OnInitializedAsync` the first to be called?

And is `OnAfterRenderAsync`where I should then hide it? Or can I do so in `OnInitialized` (no `Async`)? Or somewhere else?

I need this not only for the UI letting the user know the page is loading, but also for my bUnit tests [to have it `WaitForState()` until the page is fully rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71320560/509627). I can test for the IsLoading property to be false.

Comment: Please note this is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67990127/blazor-how-to-await-properly-for-data-to-be-loaded-before-printing?rq=2 as my issue is having all the child components complete initialization too.

Comment: Seems like OnAfterRenderAsync would be the place for this.  The neat thing about Blazor is each little component is free to do its own thing-- forcibly trying to control everything is essentially turning a SPA into a traditional html page.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I agree with all of what you said. But I'm then using `OnAfterRender` (figure no need for `Async` as all I do is set a bool false). And that violates what I think is an excellent suggestion by MrC - never use `OnAfterRenderAsync` except for JavaScript and accessing an `@ref=` property. Is this a reasonable thrid exception? TIA

Comment: Well, the problem with OnAfterRender is that-- you've rendered.  It could be annoying because you'll load your whole page, and then load something else with no user interaction.  But for your use case, this is the desired procedure: show a loading screen, and then display the page once it's ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a demo to show how the render sequence works and how the LoadingOverlay can work with sub-components.

Take the `LoadingOverlay` from the other answer:

```cs
<div class="@_css">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="alert alert-warning m-5 p-5">We're experiencing very high call volumes today [nothing out of the norm now]. 
            You're at call position 199.  You're business, not you, is important to us!</div>
    </div>
</div>
@if(this.ChildContent is not null)
{
    @this.ChildContent
}
@code {
    private string _css => this.IsLoading ? "loading" : "loaded";

    [Parameter] public bool IsLoading { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

Add the *Blazr.BaseComponents* package to the project.  `DocumentedComponentBase` is used as the base component for the components to document their lifecycle and event sequences.

Add `WeatherList.Razor`

```cs
@inherits Blazr.BaseComponents.ComponentBase.DocumentedComponentBase
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Temp. (C)</th>
            <th>Temp. (F)</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var forecast in _forecasts)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<LoadingOverlay IsLoading="_loading" />


@code {
    [Parameter] public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>? Forecasts { get; set; }

    private bool _loading = true;
    private IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> _forecasts = Enumerable.Empty<WeatherForecast>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        _forecasts = this.Forecasts ?? Enumerable.Empty<WeatherForecast>();
        _loading = false;
    }
}
```

Update `FetchData`:

```cs
@page "/fetchdata"
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService
@inherits Blazr.BaseComponents.ComponentBase.DocumentedComponentBase

<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>
<LoadingOverlay IsLoading="_loading" />


<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
        <WeatherList Forecasts="forecasts" />
}

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;
    private bool _loading => forecasts == null;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now));
    }
}
```

If you now run this code you will see the following output to the console by `DocumentedComponentBase`:

Note that `FetchData` runs it's OnInitialized sequence to completion and renders and runs it's first `OnAfterRenderAsync` before `WeatherList` is even created.

```
===========================================
4755 - FetchData => Component Initialized
4755 - FetchData => Component Attached
4755 - FetchData => SetParametersAsync Started
4755 - FetchData => OnInitialized sequence Started
4755 - FetchData => Awaiting Task completion
4755 - FetchData => StateHasChanged Called
4755 - FetchData => Render Queued
4755 - FetchData => Component Rendered
4755 - FetchData => OnAfterRenderAsync Started
4755 - FetchData => OnAfterRenderAsync Completed
4755 - FetchData => OnInitialized sequence Completed
4755 - FetchData => OnParametersSet Sequence Started
4755 - FetchData => StateHasChanged Called
4755 - FetchData => Render Queued
4755 - FetchData => Component Rendered
===========================================
d15e - WeatherList => Component Initialized
d15e - WeatherList => Component Attached
d15e - WeatherList => SetParametersAsync Started
d15e - WeatherList => OnInitialized sequence Started
d15e - WeatherList => Awaiting Task completion
d15e - WeatherList => StateHasChanged Called
d15e - WeatherList => Render Queued
d15e - WeatherList => Component Rendered
4755 - FetchData => OnParametersSet Sequence Completed
4755 - FetchData => SetParametersAsync Completed
4755 - FetchData => OnAfterRenderAsync Started
4755 - FetchData => OnAfterRenderAsync Completed
d15e - WeatherList => OnAfterRenderAsync Started
d15e - WeatherList => OnAfterRenderAsync Completed
d15e - WeatherList => OnInitialized sequence Completed
d15e - WeatherList => OnParametersSet Sequence Started
d15e - WeatherList => StateHasChanged Called
d15e - WeatherList => Render Queued
d15e - WeatherList => Component Rendered
d15e - WeatherList => OnParametersSet Sequence Completed
d15e - WeatherList => SetParametersAsync Completed
d15e - WeatherList => OnAfterRenderAsync Started
d15e - WeatherList => OnAfterRenderAsync Completed
```

The above documented sequence demonstrates that there is no way you can set a flag in `FetchData` that shows a *Loading* message that you can guarantee will not complete before sub-components start and run their `OnInitialized` sequences.

Comment: Well *#@%! There goes my simple solution. I think your idea of a "Loading..." for each relevant component makes sense. And for bUnit I'll do a WaitFor() on each component to insure all have completed. As always, thank you for the really good illustration.

Comment: NP.  `DocumentedComponentBase` is great in tracking what's happening in component render sequences.

Comment: Submitted a plea [to add a rendering complete event](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/discussions/51807) to the aspnetcore suggestions.

Comment: The answer will be to build your own base component.  You can add one yourself.  Ask a separate question and I show you how.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your intent correctly, you just need to do something equivalent to a modal dialog that "hides" the loading content.

Here's a demo using the `Weather` page.

`Loading.razor`:

```cs
<div class="@_css">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="alert alert-warning m-5 p-5">We're experiencing very high call volumes today [nothing out if the norm now]. 
            You're at call position 999.  You're business, not you, is important to us!</div>
    </div>
</div>
@if(this.ChildContent is not null)
{
    @this.ChildContent
}
@code {
    private string _css => this.IsLoading ? "loading" : "loaded";

    [Parameter] public bool IsLoading { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

`Loading.razor.css`

```css
div.loading {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 101; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.95); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

div.loaded {
    display: none;
}
```

This should work:

```cs
@page "/weather"
@attribute [StreamRendering(true)]

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>
<Loading IsLoading="_loading" />

    <h1>Weather</h1>

    <p>This component demonstrates showing data.</p>

    @if (_loading)
    {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    }
    else
    {
       //...
    }
@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;
    private bool _loading => forecasts == null;

//...
}
```

I've coded it so you can also do this:

```cs
@page "/weather"
@attribute [StreamRendering(true)]

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>
<Loading IsLoading="_loading">

    <h1>Weather</h1>

    <p>This component demonstrates showing data.</p>

    @if (_loading)
    {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    }
    else
    {
       //...
    }
</Loading>
@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;
    private bool _loading => forecasts == null;

//...
}
```

Change the transparency of `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.95);` to let what's happening in the background bleed through.

Comment: Yes but... If the outer page component completes loading, but some of the child components are still executing in their `OnInitializedAsync`, I want to keep that up. For example, I have Dashboard.razor that has almost nothing in its `OnInitializedAsync`. But it has 3 componentes that are each a grid and those grids are reading in data. So their `OnInitializedAsync` can take a couple of seconds. And I want that "Loading..." staying up until each of the children complete their `OnInitializedAsync`.

Comment: You can't do this at a top level.  Think about it.  A sub component isn't created until a component is rendered.  There's no mechanism you can use that has a holistic overview of the render process.  You need to add the overlay on any component that has a delayed render with async calls.  You may have several overlays in place at the same time, but that's the price to pay.  Once everything renders, there are no overlays.

Comment: But isn't it true that all the child component's `OnInitializedAsync()` calls will complete before any component, including the parent page, receive the `OnAfterRenderAsync ()` call? This is also a problem for bUnit where I need to know all rendering is complete before testing - and I don't know which child component will complete rendering last and therefore can't `WaitFor` the existence of a child component's html markup. ???

Comment: See my second answer to demonstrate how the Overlay will work with sub-components and why you can't guarantee `OnInitialized{Async}` will run on sub-components before  `OnAfterRenderAsync` is run on the parent.  You've read my previous comments on `OnAfterRenderAsync`.  It's a UI event, not a lifecycle process.

Comment: Yeah, I keep wanting `OnAfterRenderAsync` to be a lifecycle event. I've got to learn that wishing won't make it so. thanks

Comment: This distinction becomes much more important in Net 8 and it's different render modes.  I suspect a lot of bad code will fall over when people try to upgrade.  I'm expecting a lot of questions!

Comment: I'm already on .NET 8 (needed a feature in Entity Framework) and no problems in my code. That I'm aware of...